# Python's multiprocessing Does Not Play Nicely With threading.local?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have two processes (see sample code) that each attempt to access a threading.local object. I would expect the below code to print "a" and "b" (in either order). Instead, I get "a" and "a". How can I elegantly and robustly reset the threading.local object when I startup whole new processes?

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
l = threading.local()
l.x = 'a'
def f():
    print getattr(l, 'x', 'b')
multiprocessing.Process(target=f).start()
f()
```

edit: For reference, when I use threading.Thread instead of multiprocessing.Process, it works as expected.

Comment: it could be helpful if you specify the operating system on which this is ran...

Comment: Running under OS X at the moment, but also tested on Fedora.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both operating systems you mentioned are Unix/Linux based and therefore implement the same `fork()`ing API.
A `fork()` completely duplicates the process object, along with its memory, loaded code, open file descriptors and threads. Moreover, the new process usually shares the very same process object within the kernel until the first memory write operation. This basically means that the local data structures are also being copied into the new process, along with the thread local variables. Thus, you still have the same data structures and `l.x` is still defined.

To reset the data structures for the new process, I'd recommend the process starting function to first call for some clearing method. You could, for example, store the parent process pid with `process_id = os.getpid()` and use

```
if process_id != os.getpid(): 
   clear_local_data()
```

In the child process main function.

Comment: But are the thread identifiers also duplicated? They are different threads at that point; shouldn't threading.local handle this?

Comment: @dave How could it? The entire purpose of `fork()` is to allow the child process to continue running oblivious to the fact it was cloned. The only distinction is the return value of the `fork()` itself: 0 for the child and a process identifier of the child process for the parent.

Comment: Well, I suppose it could use something like os.getpid() to recognize that it's moved to a different thread. Perhaps this would make a good feature request.

Comment: @dave Please note that `os.getpid()` is a **process** identifier, not a *thread* identifier. This will make a bad thread identifier if your process runs more than a single thread! (They will all have the same pid)

Answer (score 4):

Because `threading.local` does the trick for threads, not for processes, as clearly described in its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local):

> The instance’s values will be different for separate threads.

Nothing about processes.

And a quote from multiprocessing [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Note
>
> multiprocessing contains no analogues of threading.active_count(),
>   threading.enumerate(), threading.settrace(), threading.setprofile(),
>   threading.Timer, or **threading.local**.

Comment: That doesn't mean the only thread of the sub-process has to keep the contents of the threading.local() object of the calling thread of the parent process.

Comment: But when I fire up a new process, that is also new thread technically, no? That is what I would expect.

Comment: every process will execute the same module level code.  so all processes will set the value to be 'a'.

Comment: @dave This depends on your meaning of word 'technically'.  So, when new 'process' is created in Python, its code is executed in a new thread within a new process.

Comment: @andrew cooke: This doesn't seem to be the case. If you replace 'a' with os.getpid() they both print out the same integer.

Comment: @roman: Right, so it's a new thread, but threading.local isn't being reset.

Comment: oh.  ok, sorry - i am confused too.  immortal's answer sounds good though.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [multiprocessing-utils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing-utils) ([github](https://github.com/daggaz/python-multiprocessing-utils/blob/master/multiprocessing_utils/local.py)) library on pypi with a multiprocessing-safe version of `threading.local()` which can be pip installed.

It works by wrapping a standard `threading.local()` and checking that the PID has not changed since it was last used (as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285933/3283790) from @immortal).

Use it exactly like `threading.local()`:

```
l = multiprocessing_utils.local()
l.x = 'a'
def f():
    print getattr(l, 'x', 'b')
f()                                        # prints "a"
threading.Thread(target=f).start()         # prints "b"
multiprocessing.Process(target=f).start()  # prints "b"
```

Full disclosure: I just created this module

Comment: I created something about 6 years ago to tackle the problem. Not as featureful as yours by any measure, of course. https://github.com/mankyd/plocal https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plocal/